# How should I set OR operators between filters?

Tags: 6, views

I'm maintaining a legacy Drupal 6 site that is running Views 2. I'm building a view that displays content of three different types. One (and only one) of these three content types has a checkbox field, and I only want nodes of that content type to be displayed by the view when that checkbox is checked.

However, as the checkbox isn't present on two of my three data types, if I set a filter that says "only show nodes where this checkbox is checked" all content of these types is excluded. How can I set a filter that says "exclude nodes where this checkbox is not checked, but only if the checkbox is present"?

Comment: Drupal 6 is outdated and is not supported any longer.

Comment: Thanks, I know. The client is a charity they is looking for funds to upgrade to D8, but at the moment we're stuck with using D6.

Comment: I think I met info before that OR in filters is available since views 3. There is a 6.x-3.x-dev version - you may want to try it on a dev setup.